# mesh gets ripped every time I try to move a square from it

Tags: mesh

I'm a blender newbie and when I try to move any square from this object's mesh it get ripped, some of the squares don't move with it.
What should I do :(
[image]

Comment: did you made this? Or is it downloaded? Sharing your object would help to solve this but it looks like it has disconnected vertices or maybe it is done by modifiers

Comment: nope I downloaded this, I searched for a solution and I found one, thank you for helping btw <3